# Why do Leans `Prop`ositions get special treatment?

Tags: types, theorem-proving, curry-howard, lean

A question is nagging me since I began going through the interactive Lean tutorial: What is the purpose of the separate `Prop` hierarchy within `Type`?

As I understand it now, we have the following universe hierarchy in place:

```
Type (n+1)
  |   \
  |   Sort (n+1)
  |     |
Type n  | (?)
  |   \ |
 ...  Sort n
  |     |
Type 0 ... (?)
  |   \ |
 nat  Prop
  |     |
  0   p ∧ q
        |
     ⟨hp, hq⟩
```

1. Are the edges marked with `?` actually there or did I just make them up (probably)?
2. From a swift look into Agda and Idris it seems they don't do the distinction between `Sort n` and `Type n`. Why does Lean distinguish them?

What feels weird about `Prop` is that it's like an inductive type on the one hand (e.g. the fact it's closed means `p ∧ nat` doesn't make sense) but used like a kind on the other hand (e.g. show *type* `p : Prop` to be inhabitated by constructing a proof *value* for `p`). I suspect that has something to do with the distinction, but I can't articulate it. Is there some basic paper to read this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just a single hierarchy of nat-indexed universes `Sort u`. From [Chapter 3 of Theorem Proving in Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/#03_Propositions_and_Proofs.html):

> In fact, the type `Prop` is syntactic sugar for `Sort 0`, the very bottom of the type hierarchy described in the last chapter. Moreover, `Type u` is also just syntactic sugar for `Sort (u+1)`.

The idea of having an impredicative bottom universe `Prop` and a predicative hierarchy `Type u` on top of it was introduced in the [Extended Calculus of Constructions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.40.5883). Lean introduces `Sort` as a single generalized hierarchy so that definitions can range over all universes using `Sort u` instead of needing separate definitions for `Prop` and for `Type u`.

In contrast, the bottom universe in Idris and Agda does not do anything special and thus they use a single name for their entire hierarchy.

Comment: Yeah, should've read that section again before posting. Thanks for the paper link!

Comment: There's also a relevant section on `Prop` in http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Universes.html, so this seems to have quite a history in Coq of which I wasn't aware.